# How did Jacob's blessing on Simeon can to pass

Tags: genesis, hebrew-bible

Jacob prophesied that Levi and Simeon will be scattered among the Israelites, it happened to Levi. Are there biblical evidences that Simeonites were scattered too?

Reference: Genesis 49:7 `A curse on their anger, for it is fierce; a curse on their wrath, for it is cruel. I will scatter them among the descendants of Jacob; I will disperse them throughout Israel.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Numbers 1:23
> The number from the tribe of Simeon was 59,300.

Simeon's number dwindled to less than half in

> Numbers 26:14
> These were the clans of Simeon; those numbered were 22,200.

Later, the territory of Simeon was absorbed by Judah due to their small number.

[image]